# Showing VIM makeprg progress on Windows

Tags: windows, vim

When VIM to used make builds using GNU make utility, there are two issues I see with the default configuration.

1. Background execution without freezing the editor.
2. Showing execution progress like emacs compile/grep command

Background execution is possible with simple !start or with plugins like dispatch or AsyncExecute etc

None of these options show the progress in a scratch window with warnings/errors emitted during build progress.

Is there anything I am missing ?

Searching the web took me to shellpipe/tee workaround which does not seem to work on Windows even after installing tee.exe

Answer (score 1):

Vim only parses the `:make` output after the command has finished.

If you launch the build asynchronously, you'd also have to periodically read the resulting output and tell Vim to parse it via `:cfile errorfile`. There may be a plugin that provides such auto-reload logic, but I'm not aware of any.

In general, there's very little asynchronicity and parallelism built into Vim (possibly due to its age and implementation in C).